How can I identify modules in lazy loaded chunk files in Angular
Could anyone help me with how angular names the chunks while building the application? I have 7 lazy modules and some extra shared modules but post building the application, I can see almost 15+ chunks in CLI and with some component names.
I am not able to understand how exactly it is lazy loading modules and compiling it. And my biggest chunk is off 15MB, and every time it is being loaded on refresh of the page which is causing a delay in page load.
I tried to search this topic but I did not find clear answer on this, any suggestions will help me a lot.
Thanks.

This is my checklist for you to solve this issue.

First check if the largest file is main.js if it is, then you can enable compression on the server, using either gzip or brotli to reduce the file size

You can increase the performance by setting vendorChunk to true in angular.json, because the main.js, will be split into two, so parallel loading

Ensure you have optimization and buildOptimizer set to true in production

Ensure you are not lazy loading the main component that gets loaded during the website load, lazy loading the home page is a bad idea, but lazy loading the other pages is a good idea

Enable namedChunks to true so that you know which chunk belongs to which lazy loaded module!



Hi, thanks for your answer, my biggest chunk is not main.js, it belongs to actually one of the lazily loaded module prefixed with some 'default_' name, I understand it is for shared modules but not sure about this big size of 15MB, here size is the main concern.

@Student18 check build analyzer
